# User a dynamic tag to extract data from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, tags

I'm writing a simple VB.net function that extracts a certain tag from an XML file. The function is :

```
Public Function ExtractXMLValue(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal XMLTag As String) As String        

    Dim XMLDocument = XDocument.Load(FilePath)
    Dim Output As String

    Output = XMLDocument.<XMLTag>.<ServerAddress>.Value
    Return Output
End Function
```

the problem is that the output is null because the program considers XMLTag as tag itself and not as dynamic string to be interpreted. And there is no tag in the XML file named "XMLTag".

And I want to call my function as for example: ExtractXMLValue(FileName, "ServerAddress")

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectionSettings>
  <ServerAddress>192.0.0.1</ServerAddress>
  <ServerPort>30000</ServerPort>
</ConnectionSettings>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.  This will find the first instance of the XMLTag in your XML doc and return it's value.  If you have more than one of the tag, it returns the first one only.  If you don't have the tag, then it will return nothing.

```
Output = XMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName(XMLTag)(0).InnerXml
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm trying to make something that will be independent from the order of the tags in the XML file. Which means, if I have my XML file as follows : `<code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ConnectionSettings>
  <ServerPort>30000</ServerPort>
  <ServerPort>30001</ServerPort>
  <ServerPort>30002</ServerPort>
  <ServerPort>30003</ServerPort>
  <ServerAddress>192.0.0.1</ServerAddress>
</ConnectionSettings><code/>` it will ill still work. Thank you

Comment: If you were to set XMLTag to "ServerAddress" using the above code, it will find "192.0.0.1" in your example.  If it were "ServerPort", it would return "30000".